# Simulate keyboard input at system level in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to control games and do free tracking using an external IMU device here by simulating keyboard inputs like left and right arrows.

I have successfully done with calling SendInput() function in C++ to simulate pressing left and right arrow. However, it doesn't actually function in a game application (even for a small flash game.)

I searched on MSDN and found that SendInput() only works in the applications of the same integrity level. So is there a way to accomplish this keyboard input simulation at system level to pass around this integrity problem?

Thanks~

Comment: That's always worked for me, but you might need a keyboard driver or something then.

Comment: Could you tell me what kind of application are you using SendInput() for?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have two applications: 1 that receives IMU tracking data and forwards it as keyboard events, and 1 that receives keyboard input and translates it as commands in a flash game. Did you try manually sending keyboard events, WM_KEYDOWN, WM_KEYUP using the SendMessage function.

Comment: @Tianyu, I honestly can't remember. I don't need to simulate input very often.

Comment: @BenjyKessler, your understanding is correct. Sorry for not explaining my problem clearly. But you get the point. I haven't tried SendMessage(), which could be a good and intuitive way to do that. For my understanding, it should be working because running a flash game rather than a huge game engine like NEED FOR SPEED will no block keyboard input stream or require lower level keyboard input. I will try SendMessage() first and I sincerely hope I will not turn into using WDK at the very end. Thanks~I will let you know how it works out.

Comment: @chris, never mind! Thanks anyway for sparing your time answering my question~^ ^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a direct answer to your question, but an alternate suggestion.

Saitek (a manufacturer of big range of game devices) always uses virtual keyboard/mouse drivers to accomplish the same task. I'd suggest you do the same. OR you can make your device a HID-compliant one at hardware level, so it can emulate keyboard/mouse/joystick without any drivers.

Comment: I think you are right about developing a HID compliant device on a hardware level. Also virtual driver is also an option. Thanks